# Why is my border overflowing into my other div?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am creating a contact portion of my portfolio but for some reason the border I set for one div is overflowing into the next div. Here is what it looks like with the code

```css
//CSS
.contact-cont {
  padding: 4rem 12rem 0rem;
  height: 90vh;

  background-color: rgb(232, 234, 246);
}

.contact {
  float: left;
  padding: 1.5rem 4rem 1.5rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.email {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.contact h1 {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
//JSX
<div className='contact-cont '>
      <div className='contact '>
        <h1>
          <strong>Let's chat</strong>
        </h1>
        <Form>
          <Form.Row>
            <Form.Group as={Col} controlId='formGridEmail'>
              <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control placeholder='Enter email' />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group as={Col} controlId='formGridPassword'>
              <Form.Label>Subject</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control placeholder='Subject' />
            </Form.Group>
          </Form.Row>
          <Form.Group controlId='exampleForm.ControlTextarea1'>
            <Form.Label>Comment</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control as='textarea' rows='10' />
          </Form.Group>

          <Button variant='primary' type='submit'>
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </div>
      <div className='email'>
        <h1>
          <strong>Or you can email me directly at:</strong>
        </h1>
        <h2>jondoe@gmail.com</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
```

:
[image]

And here is what I want it to look like:
[image]

Why is the email div overflowing into my contact form?

Comment: Your snippet doesn't match the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem must be added `float: left;` on class `.email`

```
.email {
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    float: left; /* <------------ */
}
```

Comment: That did it! I don't understand why that works though. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Because the first element `.contact` has been added `float: left`. The position of the next element depends on this float

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your `.contact` is floated. An item which is floated is basically "removed" from your flow. That's why your `.email` is spanning over the entire width of the page.

Don't float `.contact` to the left, but float `.email` to the right. You'll probably have to play with the width of both containers to get it just right.

Best thing to do after using this is to clear after your float.

```
.contact-cont:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    float: none;
}
```

This prevents other divs following your wrapper from being pushed up if your floating element would be higher than the non-floating element.